# The width of pqSelect is increasing when the method refreshData is called

Tags: javascript, css

I am using pqSelect for select field. I want to change the options in the select field. When I change the options and refresh the option list by calling refreshData method of pqSelect. It refreshes the options but it also increases the width of field. How do I correct this??.

```
$('#education').pqSelect("refreshData");
```

Before calling refreshData

[image]

After calling refreshData

[image]

```
    <select id="education" name="education[]" style="width: 100%" required="" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

Comment: Create http://jsfiddle.net/ for understanding better.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, specify width in pixels and also use `max-width`. Try `style="width:200px; max-width: 200px;"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `width="100% !important"`